# Minor leakages with CoreData or Outlet collection

Tags: swift, core-data, memory-leaks, nsfetchrequest

After several days I still can't find out why using `executeFetchRequest` is causing a small memory leak, showing in Instruments: Leaks. I'm fully aware UIKit has many leakages, but I'd like to at least try to understand it a bit better.

Whenever I execute a fetch request, it won't leak as long as I don't assign it to a class property. To explain this a bit better I've created a new project as shown below:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

    var persons = [Persons]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Persons")
        let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as! [Persons]
        persons = results     //If I comment out this line, no leak will occur
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return persons.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = persons[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }
}
```

After I change to this ViewController, a leak will show up in Instruments after approximately 10 seconds (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot]

After testing some more, creating an `outlet collection` causes a minor leakage as well. After searching for a few days, there doesn't seem to be many people having the same problem. I wonder if I did something wrong or should I just ignore this? The size of the leakages aren't that big (about 100 Bytes).

Comment: I've noticed this too when I'm profiling memory leaks and am perplexed that there are no other stack overflow posts about it. For now I've decided to add all IBOutlets individually and then have a computed var to return a collection of outlets. At least this way the leak won't show up in instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue with outlet collections leaking memory,
see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34915839/2919327).

The workaround, as mentioned by Joe Collins, is to:

"... replace [UIButton]! with NSArray! and cast its contents to UIButton later when used."

Answer (score 0):

I think the leak is the initialized `[Persons]` array that is never used but overwritten with the fetch results. Once the view controller is deallocated, the "leaked" memory will most likely be reclaimed.

According to my understanding, and in view of the scope of the issue, you can safely ignore this phenomenon.

Comment: Nope. Try it yourself.