# Swift 2 :IBOutlet Collection [UIButton]! leaks memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, swift2

Recently in my app I have found out that my UIButton outlet collection is leaking memory.

All I have is

```
    @IBOutlet var TabBarButtons: [UIButton]!
```

And from Instrument [image]

Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong?  As time goes on, the amount of variables in the NSArray keeps growing and all I have is an array with 4 UIButtons from IB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug. Reference [rdar://24272775](http://www.openradar.me/24272775)

Workaround for now is to replace [UIButton]! with NSArray! and cast its contents to UIButton later when used.